# How to replace "(" and ")" with "<span>" and "</span>" jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have follow html code:

```
<a href="#">Evente (0)</a>
```

an i need:

```
<a href="#">Evente <span>0</span></a>
```

how i can change it with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably following is cleaner in regards of jQuery functionallity:

```
$('a').html(function(i,html){ return html.replace(/\((.*?)\)/, "<span>$1</span>")})
```

Comment: This will be delete all a-tags!

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use standard JS regexp:

`str.replace(/\(/g, '<span>').replace(/\)/, '</span>')`

Comment: You should better use one regex for all of it to avoid having a single unmatched `&lt;/span&gt;` if there is stuff like a smiley.
And you might want to restrict the stuff inside the parentheses to what can occur in your app (instead of just `.*) to avoid false matches.

Comment: Thank You now it's working fine :)

$("#primary-links a").text().replace(/\\(/g, '<span>').replace(/\\)/g, '</span>');

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use jQuery.](http://azabani.com/51)

```
myAtag.innerHTML = myAtag.innerHTML.replace(/\(/,'<span>').replace(/\)/,'</span>');
```

Better still, output it from the server like that in the first place.

Comment: I think that link is more appropriate for questions where there *could* be a jQuery alternative. To my knowledge, there is no bizarre jQuery substitute for JS regexes (at least, not yet).

Answer (score 0):

My thought for using jquery;

I added an ID to the achor tag to make it simpler to reference:

```
<a id='target' href="#">Evente (0)</a>
```

And the following JQuery code

```
$('#target').html($('#target').html().replace("(","<span>").replace(")","</span"));
```

Similar to both of the above answers, but with JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SHiNKiROU
now is running goooood ;)

```
$("#content-tabs a").text().replace(/\(/g, '<span>').replace(/\)/g, '</span>');
```